# How to add a link to image

Tags: html

I am trying to create a link that is displayed on an image which should take me to a different view. I can only add a link below the image which doesn’t look very presentable. I am using basic html. Please can someone assist me?

```
<div class="card">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/B01.jpg")" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="container">
<br>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")` is **not**  basic HTML

Answer (score 3):

A link is just an `<a>` element wrapping the clickable part, which is probably most often text but can just as easily be an `<img>` element.  You can create one manually and use the `Url.Action` helper to define the URL:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index")">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/B01.jpg")" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

This code worked for me. You had to create a link to the next view and add the image afterwards. You can also use style tags to manipulate the links to your liking.

```
   <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Display name", "Controller")" title="your title" class="links">
            <br />
            <img alt="image alt" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/B01.jpg")"
                 style="width:500px;height:250px;border:0;"><br /><br /> <font size="4">Display a name</font>
        </a>
    </li>


You can also include a style

</ul>
<style type="text/css">
    ul.links {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

        ul.links li {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

            ul.links li:first-child {
                border-left: 0;
                padding-left: 10px;
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
</style>




<br />


<ul class="links"></ul>
<style>
    ul.links {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

        ul.links li {
            border-left: 0;
            padding-right: 30px;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Really sorry to say, but this code looks weird. "You can also include a style" does not belong to the code block. And there are several <br> tags in there as well as some <style> tags which seem to be superfluous. Please edit your answer and fix code and code formatting.